# Multivariate differentiation in Python

Tags: python, matlab, function, pde

I have a function

[image: Multivariate function]
that I want to simplify and differentiate in Python, defined as**

```py
def u(x, t):
    return math.erf((x + 1) / (2 * (k * t) ** (1 / 2)))
```

** Please correct me if I am wrong.

I have all the necessary imports as follows:

```py
import math
import scipy
import matplotlib
from sympy import *
```

As well as defining the symbols

```
x, k, t = symbols('x k t')
```

This works perfectly fine:

```
def f(x):
     return x ** 4

diff(f(x))
```

Which returns the correct answer,

> 4x^3

However, this

```
diff(u(x, t))
```

or this

```
diff(u(x, t), t)
```

returns an error as follows

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 diff(u(x, t))
>
> in u(x, t)
>         1 def u(x, t):
>   ----> 2     return math.erf((x + 1) / (2 * (k * t) ** (1 / 2)))
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py in **float**(self)
>       223         if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHrXh.jpg):
>       224             raise TypeError("can't convert complex to float")
>   --> 225         raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
>       226 
>       227     def **complex**(self):
>
> TypeError: can't convert expression to float

In Matlab I could easily do it:

```
syms x;
syms k;
syms t;
u = erf((x + 1)/(2 * sqrt(k * t)));
LHS = simplify(diff(u, t))
RHS = k * simplify(diff(u, x, 2))
```

My question is, how can I differentiate and/or simplify a mathematical function of more than one variable in Python?

Comment: Did you read [this documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/calculus.html#derivatives)?

Comment: Yes, I have read the SymPy documentation, however I am not sure how the syntax works regarding the following: 
`expr = exp(x*y*z)`
`diff(expr, x, y, y, z, z, z, z)`

Comment: Also, if I define my own function as such `expr = math.erf((x + 1) / (2 * (k * t) ** (1 / 2)))` and attempt to differentiate with respect to t `diff(expr, t)` I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `sympy.erf`, not `math.erf`:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x, k, t = sympy.symbols('x k t')
>>> def u(x, t):
...     return sympy.erf((x + 1) / (2 * (k * t) ** (1 / 2)))
>>> sympy.diff(u(x, t), x, t)
(0.25*(k*t)**(-1.5)*(x + 1)**2 - 0.5*(k*t)**(-0.5))*exp(-(k*t)**(-1.0)*(x + 1)**2/4)/(sqrt(pi)*t)
```

Comment: I don't get an error anymore! Thank you so much! 
However, my answer returns as 0.
How did you import `sympy` and define the symbols?

Comment: I just did `import sympy` and then your same `x, k, t = symbols('x k t')`.

Comment: mine still returns 0. I have no idea why. `import sympy

x, k, t = symbols('x k t')

def u(x, t):
    return sympy.erf((x + 1) / (2 * (k * t) ** (1 / 2)))

sympy.diff(u(x, t), x, t)`

Comment: @EfVonZee: That is strange.  I edited my answer to show my complete interpreter session.  Are you saying if you run that exact code in a newly-started interpreter, you get 0 at the end?

Comment: @EfVonZee: That's pretty baffling.  But just to double-check. . . you're running it in a brand-new interpreter session, with no other code before or after it?  If that's the case it's hard to know what could be going on.

Comment: @EfVonZee: That's doesn't look like it's in a fresh interpreter session, because it says `In [206]:`.  Try restarting your Python session and then trying it.

Comment: [link](http://i62.tinypic.com/k1yw55.jpg)  I've tried it directly in terminal running `python` as well.

Comment: @EfVonZee: Oh, I bet it's because of the `1/2`.  Try adding `from __future__ import division` to the top of the code.

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use `sympy` like this:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, diff
>>> x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
>>> diff( x**2 + y**3, y)
3*y**2
>>> diff( x**2 + y**3, y).subs({x:3, y:1})
3
```

You have to specify which variable you're differentiating with respect to.

Comment: I do import `from sympy import *`. 
Also, `diff(u(x, t), t)` also returns an error.

Comment: I think the issue may be with the constant `k`. I am not sure how that can be resolved, I would consult the documentation @BrenBarn provided.

Comment: OH! I think your issue may be caused by using `k` as a symbol. Try removing it from your symbol list.

Comment: `x, t = symbols('x t')` followed by `diff(u(x, t), t)` still returns an error :/
Also, keep in mind I am trying to differentiate symbolically, so even though `k` is a constant, I think it still counts as a 'symbol' in Python. I tested in Matlab, and removing `syms k;` does not make a difference.

Comment: @EfVonZee: Did you redefine `u` after doing that (if you're doing this interactively)?

Comment: @BrenBarn, yes I did.